# Remove this left column in VIM

Tags: vim

I was doing a DIFF in VIM, and after trying to change the color scheme, I got this annoying column, it only appears in one file, no matter if I restart VIM, now I don't know how to get rid of it.

I think it doesn't have nothing to do with GitGutter, but now I'm not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's the fold column, which displays indicators for open and closed folds. Its width is controlled by a window-local option called `'foldcolumn'` (see `:h 'fdc`).

By default, its value is `0` (disabled). If it's present in one of your window, some file must have changed its value. To find which one, you could execute:

```
:verbose setlocal foldcolumn
```